# Database quaternary relationship

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Lets say I have a database table defined with four foreign keys (FK) in it. Is it then safe to say that this table is an implementatione of a quaternary relationship? Or can there be other reasons to create a table with four FK? Is this still true if one of the FK is just a relation to a look-up table, i.e. an enum?

Are quaternary relationships found often when doing database modeling or is this such a rare case that the relation should probably have been modeled in another way in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of a quaternary relationship in a data model defines a semantically significant interaction between four independent entity-types.

It is easily conceivable that any two foreign keys in a given table implement semantically independent relationships.  For example, a `PERSON` may have a relationship to an `EMPLOYER` and another relationship to another person who is their spouse.  This would not make the `PERSON` an intersection between companies and non-employed people.

Since any two foreign keys can be semantically unrelated, if follows that not every table with four foreign keys is necessarily an implementation of a quaternary relationship.

I have no source of statistics on the frequency of quaternary relationships, but I would say that rarity is no reason to avoid using this construct if it happens to be the simplest and most appropriate way to represent the data that your system needs.

Comment: Good point, I see now that not all foreign keys need to participate in the same relationship, obviously. But what if the table represents not an entity on its own, like Person, bit instead a table existing simply to represent a n:m relationship?

Comment: I guess that one cannot make that assumption for a relationship table neither, since one of the keys can designate a property of the relationship and not be part of the relationship itself.